# Python: tarfile exclude .git folder inside tar

Tags: python, python-3.x, tar, tarfile

I've a git repo and I want to tar all the files except `.git` folder and its contents.

I've found answers with param `exclude=...` in `tar.add(...)` but it seems to be depricated. Any other ways to do it?

Comment: def filter_func(tarinfo):
   if os.path.isdir(tarinfo.name):
        return None
   return tarinfo

mytarfile.add(..., filter=filter_func)

Comment: can you try above?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do find files and skip files and use exec command to tar.

`find /dir -name "*.gz" ! -name .git -exec tar -rvf out.tar {} \;`

Comment: Thankyou but I am trying to implement this in python script using `tarfiles` python library

Comment: @Pax Not sure if it helps, but if its specific to linux machines you can try subprocess and run this command. But if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
def filter_func(tarinfo):
  if os.path.isdir(tarinfo.name):
    return None
return tarinfo

mytarfile.add(..., filter=filter_func)
```

Comment: Doesn't this script ignores all folders only, as its just checking if file is directory or not? I want to ignore only .git and subfiles